# TDB2Factory connecting dataset

Tags: jena, tdb

I try to use TDB2Factory to connect dataset (in turtle syntax) at URL address. But this command:

```
Dataset ds = TDB2Factory.connectDataset(loc1);
```

doesnt load any data. There is a problem with syntax or exists another way how to connect dataset from jena apache?

Answer (score 0):

`TDB2Factory.connectDataset` connects to the local filesystem. It does not read Turtle file but you can load data from a file using `RDFDataMgr`. This data is written to the database in the local filesystem.

Alternatively, uou can load the database first with the `tdb2.tdbloader` tool.